# calculating the partial derivative of a function w.r.t. its complex conjugate ($\frac{\partial f^{*}}{\partial f}$)

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

I was working on a problem in field theory (so physics) and the question occured to me, wether the expression $\frac{\partial f^{*}}{\partial f}$ can be determined for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ (generally).

I tried an approach inspired by Wirtinger derivatives (with $x,y: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$): 
$$ \textrm{using} \quad f = x + iy, \enspace f^{*} = x - iy \quad \textrm{and}  \quad x= \frac{1}{2}(f+f^{*}), \enspace y=\frac{i}{2}(f^{*}-f) \textrm{:} $$ 
$$\frac{\partial f^{*}(x,y)}{\partial f} = \frac{\partial f^{*}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial f}+\frac{\partial f^{*}}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial f} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + (-)i \cdot (-)\frac{i}{2} = 0 $$

---

Even though I'd like to believe thats true I am very much not sure (frankly I thing it looks  wrong). Yet I can't see where I am mistaken (my knowledge of complex analysis is...let's say: bouned). So please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go a step deeper and first define what the derivative of $f$ in the direction of $f^*$ could represent in terms of real partial derivatives and real functions $g,h$ of two real variables $x,y$. Terminology is

$$f(z) =   g(x,y) + i h(x,y)$$
$$ f^*(z) =  g(x, y) - i h(x, y)$$
$$ (f(z))^* =  g(x ,- y) - i h(x ,- y)$$

As power series, this means that g and h have real coefficients

The fundamental Riemann equations for an analytic function in the space of general functions of two independent complex variables is

$$ 0 = \partial_{z^*} f(z,z*) = \partial_x g(x,y) - i \partial_y g(x,y) + i (\partial_x g(x,y) - i \partial_y g(x,y)) = 0$$

by linearity
$$\partial_{a x + b y} f  = a \partial_x f + b \partial_y  f  $$

That is f is diffentiable and independent of  $x-iy$.

These are the concepts you are using as a primitive example, when x and y are the primary real variables in the complex plane.

As a first step, explain your idea for simplest nonlinear map.

$$\partial_{x^2-y^2 -2 i x y } (x^2 -y^2 + 2 i x y)$$

as a directional derivative when what is kept constant?